# Android MS word and ContentProvider

Tags: android, ms-word, ms-office, android-contentprovider

I have fine working content provider that communicates with a lot of applications.. It works fine. But when i try to open a document in MS word i see a label "Read only - You can't save changes to this file" and 2 options 'Save a copy' and 'Dismiss'. Other applications works good and have possibility to save back a file. Did anybody face with this problem ?
[image: MS word image]

Comment: Presumably, you are seeing a limitation in that app. There is no requirement that all apps have to allow saving back to all data sources. If you think that there may be a problem in your code, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare I think i don't have any problem in the code. I think this is a limitation on the MS Word application. But i cannot find any information in the web. so i asked here.. Also here is a link that helps implement such funcionlity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911480.aspx

Comment: What kind of content provider is that? Have you written it yourself, or is it a product that is documented somewhere? Where are the MS word documents, on the phone or somewhere else?

Comment: I have written my own ContentProvider. I implemented all required methods in right way. Docx file is in private store of my application. I share this file via ContentProvider

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @Vetalll have you found any solution for this? Or probably an alternative solution?

Comment: @Vetalll `Other applications works good and have possibility to save back a file.`. Could you give me a clue about that "Other applications"?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji This is old question. But the issue still exist.
Our company decided to get rid of ContentProvider since word is the most famous app and it does not work with ContentProvider in edit mode!

Comment: @Vetalll Alright then Thanks. Too bad :(